# How to add class to img element in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply trying to add a class to an img in an array

```
aftArray = $('.aft'); // creates array of HTML imgs
aftArray[0].addClass('currentTest'); // should change CSS by adding this class
```

Here is the resulting error from FF

```
[12:53:18.593] TypeError: aftArray[0].addClass is not a function...
```

WTF? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call addClass on DOM object instead of jQuery object. Indexer gives you do ojbect You need to use eq() to get jQuery object.

```
aftArray.eq(0).addClass('currentTest');
```

You do not have to iterate in this particular case.

```
$('.aft').addClass('currentTest');
```

Comment: It worx! Tx! I will also look at API for eq() as I had never heard of it b4.

Answer (score 0):

because `[0]` gives you the DOM element! You want to use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: ... or `:first` / `.first()`.